# Firefox fails to listen to JavaScript when "selecting" a Flash object

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash, firefox, keydown

I am currently building a website which also contains playable songs via [Grooveshark Widgets](http://widgets.grooveshark.com/). It also contains JavaScript keyDown functions, so users can use arrow keys to navigate to next and previous pages, and upvote and downvote pages.
It all works fine on all browsers except for Firefox.
On FF, the keyDown listener initially works, however as soon as I use the flash object playing the music (e.g. pause it), Firefox somehow seems to "select" the flash object, looking like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T52xD.png) (sorry, need 10 rep to post images).

While the flash object is "selected" the JavaScript key listener does not work at all. However, as soon as I click somewhere outside of the player, and it is thus "deselected", the key listener works again.
Is there a workaround for this?

Here is the code for the flash object:

```
<object width="250" height="40" classid="(some random number)"
                        id="(some random id)" name="(same as id)">
<param name="movie" value="http://grooveshark.com/songWidget.swf" />
<param name="wmode" value="window" />
<param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />
<param name="flashvars" value="hostname=grooveshark.com&songID=(song id)&style=metal&p=(1 or 0)" />
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://grooveshark.com/songWidget.swf" width="250" height="40">
<param name="wmode" value="window" /><param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />
<param name="flashvars" value="hostname=grooveshark.com&songID=(song id)&style=metal&p=(1 or 0)" />
<span><a href=(Url on Grooveshark)>(song name) by (artist) on Grooveshark</a></span></object></object>
```

And here is my key listener:

```
var map = [];

        window.onkeydown = window.onkeyup = function(e){
            e = e || event; // to deal with IE
            map[e.keyCode] = e.type == 'keydown';

            if (map[37]) { // Left Key
                window.location.href = "{{ path('sctn_history', { 'target': 'backwards' } ) }}";
            }
            else if (map[39]) { // Right Key
                {% if history_position > 0 %}
                window.location.href = "{{ path('sctn_history', { 'target': 'forwards' } ) }}";
                {% else %}
                window.location.href = "{{ path('sctn_findsong') }}";
                {% endif %}
            }
            if (map[38]){ // Up Key
                if (karma == 'none') { changeKarma('plus'); }
                if (karma == 'minus') { changeKarma('minus'); }
            }
            if (map[40]){ // Down Key
                if (karma == 'none') { changeKarma('minus'); }
                if (karma == 'plus') { changeKarma('plus'); }
            }
        }
```

Comment: `works fine on all browsers except for Firefox` Which other browsers did you test on? Google Chrome has a flash player [**integrated**](https://code.google.com/p/ppapi/), which means behaviour may differ from a browser [**loading an external plugin**](http://www.adobe.com/software/flash/about/)

Comment: I have not tested myself, I have a tester who gave me the information. I'll try it out on other browsers and let you know. If it's that, is there a way of working around it?

Comment: I have tested on Opera, on which it also works. I currently can not test IE as I am using a Mac OSX, and the flash objext on Safari currently doesn't work at all (?) - As Opera is also a Chromium-based browser with the integrated Flash player, I can assume that this is the issue. So, is there a way of solving this?